# Lag when using graphics.drawline in winforms/C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, picturebox

Beginner coder here getting into C#.. I'm making a program that involves drawing. Basically whenever I'm moving my mouse to draw, the actual line on the image appears delayed - and it's more.. straight, than it's supposed to be. It used to work fine, but at some point I guess something went wrong - can't remember what I did at the time so it's hard to retrace.. I tried to replicate just the drawing part of the program in a new solution, and it seems to work fine..

I'd post the .exe file so you can see what I mean but I'm not sure if we're allowed to post executables around here.

Edit: I've confirmed that the code works fine, look at the answer by sa_ddam213 for an example of the code. It seems as though it works fine in other peoples computers, so I'm completely confused.

Comment: Have you set the proporty 'DoubleBuffered' (or something like that) to true ?

Answer (score 1):

Yo are creating a new Graphic and Pen object with every mouse move event, this will be a lot slower than creating these variables once in the `Mouse_Down` event.

Something like this may be a bit faster.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        b = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
    }

    private Graphics _graphics;
    private Pen _pen;
    private int pX = 0;
    private int pY = 0;
    private bool paint = false;
    private Bitmap b;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        pX = e.X;
        pY = e.Y;
        _graphics = Graphics.FromImage(b);
        _pen= new Pen(Color.Black, 3);
        paint = true;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (paint)
        {
            _graphics.DrawLine(_pen, pX, pY, e.X, e.Y);
            pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = b;
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            pX = e.X;
            pY = e.Y;
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        paint = false;
        _graphics.Dispose();
        _pen.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Improved my code based on that (had to still add in the invalidate for the line to actually display). Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have fixed the underlying problem so I'm getting the exact same thing.
On the off chance this isn't against the rules, here's the exe - http://www.mediafire.com/?2ozevf1f55287a7
Someone remove it if it is :)

Comment: I can't replicate the lag, I have added my complete mockup to the answer if you want to test.

Comment: Hmmmmm, then it's possible there is so userside problem in my actual computer. Will have to pop it into some other PC to see what happens. The curious part is that if I'm trying to create a new project, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pictureBox1.Invalidate(), try using pictureBox1.Refresh()

You might also need to move it AFTER the pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = b

Also, in your MouseDown, you need to set *this.Capture* = true, and in your MouseUp you should set *this.Capture = false*. If you don't do that and you release the mouse button while your mouse cursor is over a different application, your's will never receive the MouseUp message.

Answer (score 0):

May be It's a problem with your VGA . Check with another PC and let us know

Comment: Apparently it is - I have no idea what could be causing it because other things like windows paint works fine in my PC. But I guess I'll be happy it works in other PCs :P